# echo selected items to JSON format

Tags: php, json

I am having a code like below . I am reading a JSON URL and echo some items with some if conditions. I am in need to re echo the selected items in JSON format.

```
<?php
$currentDate = date("Y/m/d");
$url         = "myURL";
$json        = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj->flightStatuses as $flightstatus) {
    echo $flightstatus->carrierFsCode, ' ', $flightstatus->flightNumber, "\n";
    if ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'G8') {
        echo "Goair\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'SG') {
        echo "Spicejet\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == '9W') {
        echo "Jetairways\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'S2') {
        echo "JetConnect\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == '6E') {
        echo "Indigo\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'AI') {
        echo "Air India\n";
    }
    ;
    if ($flightstatus->departureAirportFsCode == 'BOM') {
        echo "Mumbai\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->departureAirportFsCode == 'DEL') {
        echo "Delhi\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->departureAirportFsCode == 'SXR') {
        echo "Srinagar\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->departureAirportFsCode == 'IXJ') {
        echo "Jammu\n";
    }
    ;
    echo date('H:i:s', strtotime((string) $flightstatus->departureDate->dateLocal)), "\n";
    echo date('H:i:s', strtotime((string) $flightstatus->arrivalDate->dateLocal)), "\n";
    if ($flightstatus->status == 'A') {
        echo "Active \n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'C') {
        echo "Cancelled\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'D') {
        echo "Diverted\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'L') {
        echo "Landed\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'S') {
        echo "Scheduled\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'U') {
        echo "Unknown\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'NO') {
        echo "Not Operational\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->status == 'DN') {
        echo "Data source needed";
    } else {
        echo "Redirected\n";
    }
    "\n";
    if ($flightstatus->arrivalAirportFsCode == 'BOM') {
        echo "Mumbai\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->arrivalAirportFsCode == 'DEL') {
        echo "Delhi\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->arrivalAirportFsCode == 'SXR') {
        echo "Srinagar\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->arrivalAirportFsCode == 'IXL') {
        echo "Leh\n";
    } elseif ($flightstatus->arrivalAirportFsCode == 'IXJ') {
        echo "Jammu\n";
    }
    ;
    echo $startT = gmdate("i:s", $flightstatus->flightDurations->scheduledBlockMinutes), "\n";
    echo $flightstatus->airportResources->departureTerminal, "\n\n\n\n";
}
?>
```

The echo items in above code result me values like

```
AI 821
Air India
Delhi
11:05:00
12:25:00
Scheduled
Jammu
01:20
3



SG 852
Spicejet
Srinagar
11:55:00
12:40:00
Scheduled
Jammu
00:45




G8 187
Goair
Delhi
12:30:00
13:45:00
Scheduled
Jammu
01:15
1
```

How can I echo the output again in JSON format ?

Also if I assign a variable to

```
$startTime= "date('H:i:s', strtotime((string) $flightstatus->departureDate->dateLocal)),";
```

it throws me syntax error.

Comment: echo json_encode($str),http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Instead of echoing the items, add them to an array, and then `echo json_encode($array)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [**@Barmar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411920/echo-selected-items-to-json-format#comment23530397_16411920) above, you need to store the data into array and finally, echo json_encoded version of the array.

1. Initiate temporary array:

   Add code between this line:

   ```
   $obj = json_decode($json);
   foreach ($obj->flightStatuses as $flightstatus) {
   ```

   the code:

   ```
   $tempResponseArrays = array();
   $obj = json_decode($json);
   foreach ($obj->flightStatuses as $flightstatus) {
       $tempResponse = array();
   ```

   **Note:**

   > 1. `$tempResponseArrays`: for global response array.
   > 2. `$tempResponse`: for individual response array (used inside the loop).
2. for every echo, replace to something like this:

   ```
   if ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'G8') {
       echo "Goair\n";
   }
   ```

   change into:

   ```
   if ($flightstatus->carrierFsCode == 'G8') {
       $tempResponse['carrier'] = "Goair";
   }
   ```

   do this for the rest of your echo'ed response.
3. add temp individual array to global temp array at the very last of your loop code:

   ```
   $tempResponseArrays[] = $tempResponse;
   ```
4. Finally, after loop is done, echo the json version:

   ```
   echo json_encode($tempResponseArrays);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert value to json,You can use json_encode function,

```
        string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] );
```

**eg:**

Keep your data into an array,Insted of echoing

```
  $data['place']="Mumbai\n";
  $data['flight']="Air India\n";
```

Then use

```
 echo json_encode($data);
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can get more details

Comment: @Deonia,I updated my answer,I think you got the idea,Please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you already have the data in json format to begin with in the `$json` variable...

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I didnt get your point. where you want me to add teh above string?

Comment: The point is you start out with the data in JSON format before the foreach even starts...  Why do you want to then take it back to JSON?  Are you trying to repackage it into some other structure, an array, or an object with different properties?  Otherwise there is no point as I can tell.